# C++ Generic Table Data Structure

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, generics

Let's have a bunch of tables. Tables have columns. Each column hold data of its kind. I am looking for a structure for a generic table that would allow me to access elements at given coordinates and access individual columns.

My idea was to provide a common interface that would be implemented in children. Children would use vectors to store individual columns. There are like four tables I am working with, so I could have one object for each of them.

```
class Data {
    template < typename T >
    virtual T getElement(unsigned int row, unsigned int column) const = 0;

    template < typename T >
    virtual void setElement(unsigned int row, unsigned int column, T value) = 0;

    template < typename T >
    virtual std::vector< T > getColumn(unsigned int column) const = 0;

    template < typename T >
    virtual void setColumn(unsigned int column, std::vector< T > values) = 0;
};
```

The problem is obviously in "***error: templates may not be ‘virtual’***". What would be the best way to attack this problem? I would like to avoid using external libraries.

Petr

Comment: Is the table structure known at compile-time, or do you want a solution that can be used with any table, without recompiling?

Comment: Why do the function need to be virtual?

Comment: @ronag: because `Data` is indeed an interface. The functions are meant to be overridden in the derived classes. Otherwise, what's the use of abstract non-virtual functions?

Comment: @jalf Well, a general solution would be nice, but I know the structure of my tables.

Comment: @Vlad: Let me rephrase my question. Why does "data" need to be an interface? I don't quite see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ronag Data object stores data. It is used throughout my program, but most of the time it does not care about the exact type of the object. It just needs to access elements and columns. It does not need to know anything about the actual internal structure of the object. That's why I provide this general interface. Its implementation is left for derived classes, because only they know where to go for column #2 or element at position (20, 2) and its type.

Comment: The problem here is that the compiler cannot know how many data types the derived classes will use, so it cannot know how many virtual functions there are. That makes it very hard to create an efficient implementation. Hard enough that C++ compilers are not required to do that. You will have to cut down the generality somewhat.

Comment: @ronag: look at the definition of `Data`: a class with only pure virtual methods is actually nothing but an interface.

Answer (score 2):

Make the class template, like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Data {
    virtual T getElement(unsigned int row, unsigned int column) const = 0;

    virtual void setElement(unsigned int row, unsigned int column, T value) = 0;

    virtual std::vector< T > getColumn(unsigned int column) const = 0;

    virtual void setColumn(unsigned int column, std::vector< T > values) = 0;
};
```

This way you make your functions generic, simultaneously making the compiler happy as well.

Comment: This is not actually what the OP needs, as the columns data can have different types, whereas in your solution it's the same T.

Comment: This will compile, but I would then have to specify Data's type. I need to work with a generic Data object.

Comment: @Petr: You tried something which is illegal in C++. End of the story. And then I gave what is legal. That is start of the story. I'm sure you would like to achieve your goal, starting from something which is possible, right?

Comment: I find that often starting form what you *want* (whether or not it is possible in C++) is a much more productive way to work. Then I just need to figure out ways to trick the compiler into doing what I want. I find it much more useful than starting from something that is possible, but which doesn't actually solve my problem. ;)

Comment: @jalf: But at some point of time, you've to start from what is possible, and gradually you make changes, and do tricks, to achieve your ultimate goal. Starting from what is impossible is never useful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for folks still looking around:

You could implement a generic table using templates and modern C++.  By defaulting the template arguments, you get a usable table, but you also get the ability to strongly type it.  `std::any` allows us to mix types in the table as well.  You can use this example to add your own API, but it is usable as-is.

```
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename R = int, typename C = int, typename T = std::any> 
class Table
{
    public:
    std::map<C, T>& operator[](R x)
    {
        return this->Data[x];
    }

    std::map<R, std::map<C, T>> Data;
};

int main()
{
    Table t;
    t[0][0] = std::string("foo");
    t[0][1] = int(2112);

    std::cout << std::any_cast<std::string&>(t[0][0]) << ", ";
    std::cout << std::any_cast<int>(t[0][1]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Running version here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/WWYMppvweGNiW5Tm